# Azure Function storage account connection string

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I have a function app defined like

```
[StorageAccount("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=...;AccountName=…;AccountKey=...")]
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    [return: Queue("lets-test-this-out")]
    public static async Task<string> Run([QueueTrigger("lets-test-this-in")] Guid  guid, TraceWriter log)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {guid}");
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

where `lets-test-this-in` and `lets-test-this-out` are the name of existing storage queues under the storage account with connection string `"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=...;AccountName=…;AccountKey=..."` (copied straight from **Access keys - Connection string** in the portal). My generated function.json when I publish is like

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator-1.0.6",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "queueName": "lets-test-this-in",
      "connection": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=...;AccountName=...;AccountKey=...;",
      "name": "guid"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/FunctionAppTest.dll",
  "entryPoint": "FunctionAppTest.Function1.Run"
}
```

which the only thing suspicious about that is I don't see `[return: Queue("lets-test-this")]` being translated to any value there.

Anyways, this isn't working:

- When I try to test the function in the portal, I see `Status: 202 Accepted`, but nothing is logged in the output pane.
- When I drop a message in `lets-test-this-in`, it does not get picked up.
- Streaming logs will say `[Info] Executing HTTP request` and then nothing.

Interestingly though, if I re-publish after removing the `[StorageAccount]` attribute then I can test in the portal and see in Streaming logs that it is still being executed.

Possibly related is that my `local.settings.json` is like

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StorageAccount` attribute accepts a name of Application Setting where the connection string is placed, not the connection string itself. E.g.

```
[StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")]
```

Output bindings are not shown in generated `function.json` - that's confusing but expected.

Comment: Actually, the documentation for the Parameters says `- Can be an app setting or connection string name of your choosing` as one of three possibilities

Comment: @SeeSharp Mikhail is right, please refer to [function document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---attributes).

Comment: @SeeSharp Yes, and yours is neither app setting name, nor connection *name*